# Is there a way to resize iframe content dynamically based on iframe height and width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, resize

Right now I have a plotly graph up on Heroku that I am trying to embed in a site via iframe. Based on what the user selects, the content can change size (height and width). I want the content to always fit inside the iframe without scrolling. The best way I can think of doing it is to zoom the inner webpage out until it's width and height are equal to or smaller than the iframe's width and height, but I'm not sure if this can be done or if it's even a good way of doing it.

I have tried using css (zoom: 0.8; etc.) but it doesn't seem to do anything. I have also tried transform: scale() and a bunch of other things, but 1) these solutions only work on the iframe itself (e.g. using scale() the iframe gets smaller, not it's content), and 2) these solutions aren't dynamic because I can't use them to change the size of the page inside. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i don't know what Heroku means, but I'm gonna answer it globally

If your trying to open one of your pages in an iframe inside another page (your iframe runs on the same DOMAIN with original source of it) it is Possible,,, VIA Javascript

If you're trying to open a page from another DOMAIN into your iframe (cross-origin) it's not possible because of CORS policies

There are different ways to do it using js (assuming you're on same origin) but this one i believe is the best

```
  var cssLink = document.createElement("link");
  cssLink.href = "style.css"; 
  cssLink.rel = "stylesheet"; 
  cssLink.type = "text/css";

  frames['Frame_NAME_Here'].document.head.appendChild(cssLink);
```

Comment: I am using a site on a different domain. Does that mean I can't do it at all? Is there not a way to adjust the zoom or anything from outside? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: sorry but i know no way for it... CORS policies are strict